# NGINX upstream proxy chaining

Tags: nginx

My web server is currently flooded with content spammers.

I don't want to completely block the IPs using iptables because they are from dynamic IPs and if I block one IP then after a few minutes the spam comes from another IP so I assume it uses a bot net of infected PCs which probably do reconnects and I don't want to end up in completely blocking an whole ISP or to permanently block tor exit nodes. So I want to use *soft* blocking similar to what cloud-flare and google do. They display a webpage for those bad scored IPs containing a information why they are blocked and a possibility to unblock.

I also have a solution how I could achieve that, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to solve that.

I have a catch all rule that will pass the request to my application that scores the IP, if the IP is has a bad score the info page will be displayed with a 502 error. If the IP is fine then a 418 is returned and the request is passed to `@final-pass`

```
location ~ {
  error_page 500 418 = @final-pass;

  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_intercept_errors on;
  proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/ip-check.sock;

}
```

Then I have the `@final-pass` this one will forward the request to a second nginx instance which has a regular setup will all virtual hosts:

```
location @final-pass {
  proxy_read_timeout      300;
  proxy_connect_timeout   300;
  proxy_redirect          off;
  proxy_buffering off;

  proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

  proxy_request_buffering off;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

<del>Is there a better or correct way how to solve that. The `418` error seems to be a bit ugly.</del>

**EDIT**
Is there a better/correct way to achieve that I can  pass the request to one upstream first, and if the request is not handled by that upstream pass it to another one, without abusing the `418` error?

**EDIT2** `444` might be a better error code, but the question is still the same, is there a better way then using an error for that kind of *forwarding*.

Comment: You question (or rather its lack thereof) is unclear. If it is 'Is there a better way?', I would use `location /` instead of the ugly `location ~`. As for the `418` HTTP status code, the standard for your case would be `403`, but `418` is a nice joke. :oD

Comment: @BernardRosset Why should the standard for that case be `403`? In my setup nginx will send the request to `ip-check.sock`. If this upstream responds with a status code that is different to `418`  then it will be delivered to the client. I choose `418` because it has no meaning, but is still reserved. If `418`  is returned then the request is _forwared_ to the actual application. The `418` status code will never be send to the client, it is just used to as hack so that the request can be send to the actual upstream.

Comment: You are right about `403`: you are not systematically forbidding access on the first lookup. For your HTTP status code 'problem', [the list of assigned status codes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) does not say a thing about `418` or `444`, which are both officially unassigned. That means there is no standard status code for the message you want to emit, you are thus free to choose any unassigned one. Some use `418` as a reference to the [HTCPCP-TEA](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7168#section-2.3.3) joke.